# Iframe doesn't work in website wile hotlinking is deactivated on remote server

Tags: apache, security, nginx, iframe

I have an unusual problem when I used an iframe on a site i'm building. The hotlink protection is off on both servers. The iframe still doesn't work. both are ssl sites. What is strange is I can add a subdomain to the website where the webpage for the iframe, and redirect to the other server, and the site shows up in the iframe after that, but directly it doesn't. Is there by chance a setting on the webserver that doesn't allow external iframes? Is it better to just leave this alone and do a subdomain hop (I'm wondering if the web host guys at hostgator did that on purpose for security, and I should just do the hop method i stumbled upon). both servers are running nginx, webserver is using nginx+apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iframes on external sites can be prevented with HTTP Header like `X-Frame-Options`

Documentation can be found from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

This header can be set by either the web server or the software that is running on the web server.

Comment: I know of this, and I read about it here: https://geekflare.com/secure-apache-from-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options/  but I don't have access to the http config, the site that is in iframe is in the allowed sites in the gaterhost panel. The in-line web page fix doesn't work for me either. I know this keeps the layman from clickjacking, but I actually had to block ip addresses before when they do the php file_get_contents work around.

Comment: I'm going to mark it as solved, because I didn't do anything and it works now.... still strange I guess something rebooted over the night.... Now I know why my friend calls the Internet "The Digital Djini"

Answer (score 0):

well, I got it working. in the .htaccess (after I turned back on hotlinking)

I wrote after the  RewriteEngine on line:

```
         AllowOverride All
    Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.theothersite.com/"
```

and it works! of course I added the http and https urls too on the exception list. now I can Iframe and use document-forms POST method